# ScriptEngine clear and dispose

Tags: java, nashorn, scriptengine

My application uses a `ScriptEngine` to offer plugin-ability to my end-users.

```
ScriptEngineManager engineManager = new ScriptEngineManager();
ScriptEngine engine = engineManager.getEngineByName("nashorn");
```

Whenever a user makes changes to his script, then the application replaces the engine instane by a new instance.

```
String newScript = ...;
engine = engineManager.getEngineByName("nashorn");
engine.eval(newScript);
```

**Two closely related questions:**

- Should I try to **reuse engines** and perform some kind of `clear()` on them ?
- If I just replace my engine with a new instance, **should I dispose the previous instance** in some way, to avoid memory leaks ? (e.g. I can imagine that the user could manage to create a script that starts a thread.)

The problem is, **I cannot find any method that looks like a `clear()` or a `dispose()`**. Does that mean that my current approach is correct ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use a single engine instance but use separate `Bindings` objects. `Bindings` acts as a top-level program environment, so if you want to evaluate a script into what is basically a "new global scope" then you could do that. Look into `javax.script` [API docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/script/ScriptEngine.html#eval-java.lang.String-javax.script.Bindings-) on how to do this. You can either use `ScriptEngine.eval` that takes a `Bindings` as second argument or the one that takes `ScriptContext` as second argument.

Even if there's no script code surviving from the previous evaluation, you'll save some initialization time as the script engine will already have predefined various JavaScript data-holder classes and property maps ("hidden classes").

Also: yes, everything is garbage collected. There's no need for an explicit "disposal" API.

Comment: Everything is crystal clear, however as for the *"no need to dispose"* part, see my answer below: apparently java doesn't clean up running threads for you.

Answer (score 6):

I just wanted to share what I tested myself. It makes perfect sense, but for those still in doubt: **Created threads do continue to run if you just replace engine instances**:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws ScriptException {
    ScriptEngineManager manager = new ScriptEngineManager();

    String script =
            "new java.lang.Thread(function() {\n" +
            "  for(;;) {" +
            "    print('Here\\'s Johnny !');" +
            "    java.lang.Thread.sleep(1000);" +
            "  }\n" +
            "}).start();";

    ScriptEngine engine = manager.getEngineByName("nashorn");
    try {
        engine.eval(script);
    } catch (ScriptException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    
    // replace engine
    engine = manager.getEngineByName("nashorn");
    engine.eval("print('please, make it stop!!!');");
    
    // please collect !!!
    System.gc();
}
```

Output:

```
    Here's Johnny !
    please, make it stop!!!
    Here's Johnny !
    Here's Johnny !
    Here's Johnny !
    ...
```

I guess that **the garbage collector can clean the scripts, but not their actions outside their context**. I think created threads are not even linked to the scripts in any way (i.e. outside their scope). So, I think it's just impossible for the jvm to detect or decide that these threads are linked to a replaced script and may or may not be stopped.

But this leads us too far for one stackoverflow question. **Let's just focus on the ability to dispose/clear the bindings (i.e. `ScriptContext`).**

## Block java threads in nashorn scripts:

A possible solution, is to narrow down the available functionality. Here follow a couple of ways to avoid the creation of threads:

The following disables all java functionality:

```
// the option -nj is short for --no-java
ScriptEngine engine = new NashornScriptEngineFactory().getScriptEngine("-nj");
```

**But you can also disable specific classes, using a `ClassFilter`.**

```
    ScriptEngine engine = new NashornScriptEngineFactory().getScriptEngine((className) -> {
        if ("java.lang.Thread".equals(className)) return false;
        if ("java.lang.Runnable".equals(className)) return false;
        if ("java.util.Timer".equals(className)) return false;
        if (className.startsWith("java.util.concurrency")) return false;
        if (className.startsWith("javafx")) return false;
        if (className.startsWith("javax.swing")) return false;
        if (className.startsWith("java.awt")) return false;
        return true;
    });
```

Note: as soon as you define a `ClassFilter` also reflection classes are blocked automatically. So, you don't have to block those packages explicitly.